# Google Maps: Include Marker/Icon in link to google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

Is it possible to link to a Google map (hosted by google, link starting with maps.google.com) and include a marker/icon?

E.g. I have the following link:

https://www.google.ch/maps/@47.5677272,7.6109065,14z?hl=de

Can I do something like this:

https://www.google.ch/maps/@47.5677272,7.6109065,14z?hl=de&iconurl=url/on/my/server&iconpos=47.5677272,7.6109065

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want a map that displays a marker at the specified coordinates. See if this link is what you need. just add `place` and two slash

[map link](https://www.google.ch/maps/place//@47.5677272,7.6109065,14z/)

Comment: it seems, you did not understand my question. I edited it to clarify it.

Comment: one step further. great, thanks. now how do I change the marker icon (from the google needle to an image url)?

Comment: I can help you only with the marker needle and if you find this useful rate the answer. Otherwise ... i don't find nothing  other on google doc..